# I want to remove a line an xml file after writing in it

Tags: java, xml

I have this code ,that parse a file xml ,I want ,after writing in this file,to remove the second line ,but I don't know how to do it?

**this is my code:**

```java
File file = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\\test.xml");

dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
dos.writeBytes(var2);  //after writing I want to remove the second line

try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    System.out.println("Information of all steps");

    for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {
        Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
            System.out.println("oooo"+fstElmnt.toString());
            // NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("step");
            String fst = fstElmnt.getAttribute("name");
            System.out.println("name : "+fst); //display steps un step
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
I want to remove a node that generate an error when I try to parse the file ,so I should remove this node before trying to parse the file
```

Comment: What happens if someone adds a comment to the top of that XML file? I'm willing to bet that you actually want to delete a line containing specific info, and it just so happens that that is the second line. I suggest to instead add some logic that parses the line contents as it writes them, and then simply don't write the line that contains that content that you don't want in the file. On the other hand, I could be wrong, and your situation could be as simple as just deleting the second line...

Answer (score 4):

A "line" has no meaning in an XML file. It's perfectly legal for the file to contain no line breaks, or for it to break lines at arbitrary points (for example, between attributes).

Instead, you want to remove a particular element from the file, or remove text from the element (it's unclear from your question which you want). To do the former, you call [Node.removeChild()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#removeChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) on the *parent*. For the latter, you can call [Node.setTextContent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent%28java.lang.String%29) with an empty string or null.

The trick is finding the node that you want to replace. It looks like you're walking through the DOM. However, a much more elegant approach is to use XPath.

Comment: If you're going for elegance, why not suggest XSLT? Seems to be much closer to a solution than XPath on its own.

Comment: @parsifal,I want to remove a node that generate an error when I try to parse the file ,so I should remove this node before trying to parse the file so why I could not use Node.removeChild() !

Comment: @rym - then why didn't you say that in the original post, instead of dumping code that parses the file? You'll get much better answers if you describe the **actual** problem, including **actual** code and **actual** stack traces.

Comment: @parsifal,I'am sorry this is a bad question :(